# php mysql поиск совпадений

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы: cheats, users.
В таблице cheats есть столбец procname, в этом столбце находятся данные. Нужно сделать поиск совпадений по таблице users, по столбцу proclist. В столбце proclist данные хранятся в одном потоке, поэтому нужно использование like. 
Написал такой код, но выводит ошибку Array to string conversion in line 39

```
$qr_result2 = mysql_query("select procname from cheats ")
or die(mysql_error());
while($cheat = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result2)){ 

$qr_result = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE proclist like     
'%".$cheat."%'")
 or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
echo '<center>'. $data['ip'] . '</center>';
}
}
 mysql_close($connect_to_db);
```

39 строчкой есть

```
$qr_result = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE proclist like '%".$cheat ."%'")
```

Comment: не в тему, но прислушайтесь и передайте другим - используйте mysqli http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` - возвращает массив, а значит, что `$cheat` - является массивом, а вы его пытаетесь вставлять в строку. Поэтому вам и говорят, что невомозможно массив преобразовать в строку.

Посмотрите, что именно у вас лежит в `$cheat`, скорее всего надо писать так `$cheat[0]`.

Comment: сделал $cheat[0], помоголо) спасибо
только почему-то, оно вывело на экран запись 4 раза, хотя в таблице users  одна запись

Comment: @Drop может быть в `cheats` четыре записи?) и нужно брать как раз procname в зависимости от юзера? это надо смотреть что у тебя имеется, что ты делаешь и что ты хочешь)

Comment: в cheats более 100 записей